# Dictionary of functions declared before the function definitions

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following code:

```
my_dict = {"function1" : function1, "function2" : function2}
def call_functions():
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        mydict[key]()

def function1():
    print "hello 1"

def function2():
    print "hello 2"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    call_functions()
```

My understanding is that this should work - while `mydict` is being declared *before* the functions are defined, python is calling them based on a name, not based on an actual pointer to the functions. Since by the time the code is run, they do exist (because this happens through main), there should be no issue. However, I get the dreaded NameError - telling me that function1 doesn't exist.

Short of declaring my_dict at the *end* of the file (I'd like to keep globals at the top where they're user-accessible), is there a way around this? I don't understand as by the time I call the function, it *has* been declared

Comment: `{"function1" : function1, "function2" : function2}` creates a dictionary before creating the functions, so when searching for function1 it gives you NameError

Comment: "I don't understand as by the time I call the function, it has been declared" - the function might exist by the time you try to *call* it, but it doesn't exist when you try to put it in the dict. You can't just put unevaluated names in a dict - that code attempts to evaluate the `function1` and `function2` names to build the dict, and those names don't evaluate to anything yet.

Comment: If python doesn't actually resolve until the point of calling, why does it care if it doesn't exist _yet_? Shouldn't the error be thrown at call time, not at definition time?

Comment: What makes you think Python doesn't try to resolve the function until you call it?

Comment: That was my understanding of how python works, based on prior reading which I now cannot find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon interpreting the first line, the 'function1' and 'function2' variables are referenced but have yet to be declared and so the program crashes as you've seen.

Move the function declarations before the my_dict line and it will work. You also had a typo which I've corrected here. (mydict vs my_dict)

```
def function1():
    print("hello 1")

def function2():
    print("hello 2")
    
my_dict = {"function1" : function1, "function2" : function2}
def call_functions():
    for key in my_dict.keys():
        my_dict[key]()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    call_functions()
```

Edit: as @chepner suggested, unless there's something beyond this context that would provide a good reason, keeping the functions in a dictionary is unnecessary where a list would suffice. See example below.

```
def function1():
    print("hello 1")

def function2():
    print("hello 2")

my_list = {function1, function2}
def call_functions():
    for func in my_list:
        func()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    call_functions()
```

Comment: Another suggestion: `key` is only used to get the value of `my_dict[key]`; you can iterate over `my_dict.values()` directly to get the functions to call. (Which calls into question why this is a `dict` and not a `list`, but the dict may be used differently in code not shown.)

Comment: @chepner thank you, I have added that as an extension.